# .Net Framework/C# - --grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Access is denied issue

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a .Net 4.7.2 project and I've set my Messages project up with the NuGet package v2.26.0. I have protoc in my environments file path and can run commands like protoc --version etc.

When trying to generate my grpc code, I run the following command:

C:\Samples\MyGrpc>protoc -I .\pb --csharp_out .\Grpc\Messages .\pb\messages.proto --grpc_out .\Grpc\Messages --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=.\Grpc\packages\Grpc.Tools.2.26.0\tools\windows_x64
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Access is denied.

I am running this command from a Windows cmd prompt opened as Administrator.

My main Visual Studio project folder is Grpc with the Message project under it.

I'm unsure what I'm being denied access to. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I figured out that the problem was that in the --plugin command, I had to put the name of the plugin executable, ie, the whole path including .exe name. It worked then.

C:\Samples\MyGrpc>protoc -I .\pb --csharp_out .\Grpc\Messages .\pb\messages.proto --grpc_out .\Grpc\Messages --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=.\Grpc\packages\Grpc.Tools.2.26.0\tools\windows_x64\grpc_csharp_plugin.exe

Thanks!

Comment: you should accept your answer as  the true answer to your question; since calling the `grpc_csharp_plugin.exe` by its absolute or relative path and its full name is the right answer.