# protoc-gen-grcp: Access is Denied. -> Visual Studio 2019, C#, Grcp

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, grpc

I created a grpc project in Visual Studio 2019 based on this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). After creating the project, I should be able to run the program 'out of the box' but I'm getting an Access Denied error (see pic). [image: Access Denied error]

The --grpc_out part is confusing me. Any help, or general pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

Other Info:
I've installed Google.Protobuf, Grpc.Net.Client, and Grpc.Tools through the NuGet package manager.

The code in the .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.48.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Check out [this SO post if you haven't already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59615603/net-framework-c-grpc-out-protoc-gen-grpc-access-is-denied-issue).  --grpc_out is probably the location of the generated C# code by protoc, if you [check the google docu](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp-generated). Maybe you just have an issue with access rights or there is something wrong with Visual Studio, if its not the linked issue? The MS Docs example that you linked worked multiple times for me without any problems, although I build it for different frameworks

Comment: Thank you @dan-kli. I saw the article and I don't think (at least right now) that is my issue. I tried the same process on my personal machine at home and it worked without any problems; so I believe it is an access rights issue and I've reached out to our IT group. I will update this post when I hear something definitive back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was related to McAfee blocking protoc.exe. My IT group is looking into adding an exception so this won't happen again. [image: McAfee]